# Calling sibling method after xhr request in custom dojo amd module

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I have a custom module for dojo's amd that will be something like this:

```
define(
  "my/moduleName",
  [//dependencies], 
  function(xhr) {
    return {
      method1: function() {
        xhr.get({
          url: "myurl",
          load: function(data) {
            //handle data
            this.method2(data) //< THIS CAUSES ERROR: 'this.method2 is not a function'
          }
        });
      },

      method2: function(data) {
        //process data
      }
    }
}
```

I suspect my problem is that `xhr.get` creates a deferred object, and `method2` is not defined in that object but rather on the "my/module" object.

How can I make the `method1` call `method2` AFTER the `xhr` has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the current `this` context as once you are inside the `load` function context `this` is the xhr object.

A common convention is `var that = this;` then use `that` inside any other closure as needed.

Store `this` before the call similar to this:

```
define(
    "my/moduleName", [ //dependencies], 
function (xhr) {
    return {
        method1: function () {
            var that = this; //<-- store this context

            xhr.get({
                url: "myurl",
                load: function (data) {
                    //handle data
                    that.method2(data); //<-- use that , the stored context
                }
            });
        },

        method2: function (data) {
            //process data
        }
    }
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4Q8/) - Store `this` for later use in another closure

---

Comment: true, but I wrote this in stackoverflow's editor to illustrate my problem, I'm not having that issue with my actual code. I'll edit the question to reflect your input though

Comment: @rantsh: You should always post code as you are using it or the issue could be miss-interpreted :) You can store your actual `this` context inside the function first, then use the cached context when needed. A common convention is `var that = this` than later use `that` where needed.